# Swinging pendulum does not work

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having a little trouble with this project. I have to create a pendulum using key handles and the code I have for the key's up and down don't seem to be working. "up" is suppose to make the pendulum go faster and "down" makes it go slower. This is the code that I have so far. can somebody please help.

```
from tkinter import * # Import tkinter
import math
width = 200
height = 200
pendulumRadius = 150
ballRadius = 10
leftAngle = 120
rightAngle = 60

class MainGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk() # Create a window, we may call it root, parent, etc
        self.window.title("Pendulum") # Set a title

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.window, bg = "white", 
                             width = width, height = height)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.angle = leftAngle # Start from leftAngle
        self.angleDelta = -1 # Swing interval
        self.delay = 200
        self.window.bind("<Key>",self.key)
        self.displayPendulum()
        self.done = False
        while not self.done:
            self.canvas.delete("pendulum") # we used delete(ALL) in previous lab
                                           # here we only delete pendulum object
                                           # in displayPendulum we give the tag
                                           # to the ovals and line (pendulum)
            self.displayPendulum()          # redraw 
            self.canvas.after(self.delay) # Sleep for 100 milliseconds
            self.canvas.update() # Update canvas


        self.window.mainloop() # Create an event loop

    def displayPendulum(self):
        x1 = width // 2;
        y1 = 20;

        if self.angle < rightAngle:
            self.angleDelta = 1 # Swing to the left
        elif self.angle > leftAngle:
            self.angleDelta = -1 # Swing to the right

        self.angle += self.angleDelta
        x = x1 + pendulumRadius * math.cos(math.radians(self.angle))
        y = y1 + pendulumRadius * math.sin(math.radians(self.angle))

        self.canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x, y, fill="blue", tags = "pendulum")
        self.canvas.create_oval(x1 - 2, y1 - 2, x1 + 2, y1 + 2, 
                                fill = "red", tags = "pendulum")
        self.canvas.create_oval(x - ballRadius, y - ballRadius, 
                                x + ballRadius, y + ballRadius,
                                fill = "green", tags = "pendulum")
    def key(self,event):
        print(event.keysym)
        print(self.delay)
        if event.keysym == 'up':
           print("up arrow key pressed, delay is",self.delay)
           if self.delay >10:
               self.delay -= 1
        if event.keysym == 'Down':
            print("Down arrow key pressed,delay is",self.delay)
            if self.delay < 200:
                self.delay += 1
        if event.keysym=='q':
            print ("press q")
            self.done = True
            self.window.destroy()

    MainGUI()
```

Comment: I've removed the word python from your question title, and split some lines so that less scrolling is necessary to read your code. Think about what precisely is not working and then add that into the question, and maybe rewrite the question to ask that.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is that the event keysym is `"Up"` but you are comparing it to the all-lowercase "up". Naturally, the comparison fails every time. Change the if statement to `if event.keysym == 'Up':`

**Improving the animation**

In case you're interested, there is a better way to do animation in tkinter than to write your own infinite loop. Tkinter already has an infinite loop running (mainloop), so you can take advantage of that.

Create a function that draws one frame, then have that function arrange for itself to be called again at some point in the future. Specifically, remove your entire "while" loop with a single call to `displayFrame()`, and then define `displayFrame` like this:

```
def drawFrame(self):
    if not self.done:
        self.canvas.delete("pendulum")
        self.displayPendulum()
        self.canvas.after(self.delay, self.drawFrame)
```

**Improving the bindings**

Generally speaking, your code will be marginally easier to manage and test if you have specific bindings for specific keys. So instead of a single catch-all function, you can have specific functions for each key.

Since your app supports the up key, the down key, and the "q" key, I recommend three bindings:

```
self.window.bind('<Up>', self.onUp)
self.window.bind('<Down>', self.onDown)
self.window.bind('<q>', self.quit)
```

You can then define each function to do exactly one thing:

```
def onUp(self, event):
    if self.delay > 10:
        self.delay -= 1

def onDown(self, event):
    if self.delay < 200:
        self.delay += 1

def onQuit(self, event):
    self.done = True
    self.window.destroy()
```